# block search engine crawling directory

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

My site have URL (longest) structure like this

http://www.example.com/xyz-pqr/abcd-efgh/123.html

So there is maximum of 3 directory level, but because of CMS and other problem my site is getting indexed in search engine for more than 3 directory level url like,

```
http://www.example.com/xyz-pqr/abcd-efgh/xyz-pqr/abcd-efgh/123.html
http://www.example.com/xyz-pqr/abcd-efgh/xyz-pqr/abcd-efgh/abcd-efgh/123.html
```

I want to write code in robots.txt so that, search engine will never crawl more than 3 directory level. How do I do this? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *certain*, but I think the following should work:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/*/*/
```

So, given these two URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/xyz-pqr/abcd-efgh/123.html
http://www.example.com/xyz-pqr/abcd-efgh/foo-bar/123.html
```

The first would be accepted because it has only two directory segments (`/xyz-pqr-abcd-efgh`).

The second would be blocked because it has three directory segments.

And anything longer would be blocked, as well.